# Is there a way to find out who is importing a package?

Tags: packages, contexts, debugging

After calling some functions, if I look into `$ContextPath`, I can see that `` JLink` `` is in there. Is there a way to find out what sequence of functions calls (like a stack-trace) imported a particular package?

Something like `FuncA` called `FuncB` which called `FuncD` which executed `` Needs["JLink`"] ``

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, here is a suggestion: you can overload `Needs` using Villegas-Gayley trick. To do this safely, here is a generator for local environments, where `Needs` will be overloaded:

```
createTraceEnvironment[context_String]:=
    Module[{inNeeds},
        Function[                
            code,
            Internal`InheritedBlock[                    
                {Needs},                    
                Unprotect[Needs];
                Needs[context]/;!TrueQ[inNeeds]:=
                    Block[{inNeeds=True},
                        Print[Stack[_][[3;;-5]]];Needs[context]
                    ];
                Protect[Needs];
                code
            ],
            HoldAll
        ]
    ];
```

Now here is how it can be used: first create a local environment for `` "JLink`" ``:

```
env = createTraceEnvironment["JLink`"];
```

Now it can be used, for example:

```
env[Needs["DatabaseLink`"]]
```

> ```
> {
>     Needs[DatabaseLink`],
>     <<DatabaseLink`,
>     <<DatabaseLink`DatabaseLink`;, 
>     <<DatabaseLink`DatabaseLink`, Get[ToFileName[/Applications/Mathematica_10_Sep_26_2013.app/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Kernel,DataSources.m]];Get[ToFileName[/Applications/Mathematica_10_Sep_26_2013.app/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Kernel,SQL.m]];,
>     <</Applications/Mathematica_10_Sep_26_2013.app/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Kernel/SQL.m,
>     Needs[JLink`];
>  }
> ```

But loading packages (or executing other code) which load `` "JLink`" ``, without the local environment, will go as usual. For example, `RLink` also loads `JLink`, but here nothing is printed:

```
Needs["RLink`"] 

(* Null *)
```