# Why does `Block` reset `Attributes`?

Tags: evaluation, scoping, attributes

Not even "formal symbols" such as `\[FormalX]` are guaranteed to always be symbolic. Their `Protected` argument is forgotten when they are used in `Block` and consorts, causing functions relying on symbolic variables to misbehave:

```
foo[n_] := Exponent[\[FormalX]^n, \[FormalX]];

foo[5]
Attributes@\[FormalX]

Table[{Attributes@\[FormalX], foo[5]}, {\[FormalX], 
  1}](*or Block[{\[FormalX]},...]*)
```

> 5
>
> {Protected}
>
> {{{}, 0}}

Why does `Block` clear `Attributes`? Is Unprotecting and changing a (system) symbol so common that it was decided that `Block` should do the `Unprotecting` unsolicitedly?

Is the only way to be sure that some symbol does not have an `OwnValue` to use `Module` or `Block`?

Comment: `SetAttributes[x, Protected]; Table[x, {x, 2}]`?

Comment: That is the point of `Block`, isn't it? Or is your question why `Table` is based on `Block`?

Comment: If you're looking for something to eliminate `OwnValues`, check out [``Internal`LocalizedBlock``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71881/52).

Comment: Or `Internal`InheritedBlock` perhaps.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau that, too. But, then you have to remove those pesky `*Values` that remain. :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau @rcollyer LocalizedBlock also removes Attributes, InheritedBlock doesn't, that's nice to know. My question is why `Block` does anything else but `old = x; x = new; ... code ...; x = old` (ensuring the reset happens even after `Throw` and `Abort`). I don't understand why it removes all definitions and Attributes altogether, instead of just giving a (new) OwnValue. It would also be more efficient to just give a new OwnValue, not bothering with other values, no?

Comment: It seems a bit inconsistent that attributes are removed when you give plain symbols to the "effectively using `Block`"-constructs, while they are preserved when you give compound expressions. `Table[\[FormalX][0], {\[FormalX][0], 1}]` gives an error.

Comment: `Block` can't do `x = new;` if `x` is `Protected`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `SetAttributes[x, Protected]; Block[{x = 5}, x]`?

Comment: @rcollyer `x` is not `Protected` inside `Block`.  If `Block` did not clear the attribute, the assignment would fail and so would `Block[{x}, x = 5]` (and my first example, too).  Or is `x` protected when the assignment `Block[{x = 5}...` is made?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm sorry, I misunderstood. It seemed that you were arguing that `Block` did not `Unprotect` `x`, and it is clear it must. So, disregard. :)

Answer (score 6):

It is illustrative to compare `Block`, `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``, `Module`, and `With`. Both `Module` and `With` create unique versions of the variables which are not accessible from the outside (lexical scoping, and not without [its issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119410/52)), e.g.

```
x = 2 y^2 - 7;
With[{y = 5}, x]
Module[{y = 5}, x]
```

where both `With` and `Module` return `-7 + 2 y^2`. `With` has the added ability to bypass `Hold` attributes, which is very useful [sometimes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/52). Because of this, it would be difficult to use them to run arbitrary code passed in by a user. In contrast, `Block` and `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` allow you to temporarily augment/overwrite an existing variable, and guarantee that the changes are reset.

A useful example of augmentation, is automatically resetting changes made to default `Options`, e.g.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Plot},
  SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}];
  Options[Plot, PlotStyle]
]
(* {PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}} *)
```

vs

```
Options[Plot, PlotStyle]
(* {PlotStyle -> Automatic} *)
```

which can be used to generate many plots where the options are uniform, without resorting to crafting a [unique theme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54637/52). A more interesting example is this [graphics parser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32719/52) which uses `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` to mimic a stack in tracking the state. If you want a more extensive augmentation, though, you still need to `Unprotect` the symbol. This is where `Block` comes in as quite often you do not want to just augment the behavior, but overwrite it entirely.

This is the use case for `Plot`, `Table`, etc. where the user supplies a symbol/expression that needs to be evaluated without worrying about whether it has `*Values`. [`` Internal`LocalizedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71881/52) extends this further by localizing things like `Subscript[x, 1]` which `Block` cannot handle.

Of course all these can be merged. Consider this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33956/52) from Leonid which traces what packages auto-load another package. It uses `Module` to set up a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) which uses the [Villegas-Gayley pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39924/52) to augment `Needs`. Here `Block` plays the important role of blocking recursive execution.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126325/12).  Is our suspicion that this is a RegionPlot (not Graphics) option true?  If yes, is it a bug that the option is passed down to Graphics?  Just mentioning in case there's an opportunity for improvement.  There's no practical problem.

Answer (score 6):

`Block` does something very simple: it just (temporarily) removes all definitions directly associated with a symbol, and nothing else.  That includes:

- `OwnValues`, `DownValues`, `UpValues`, `SubValues`, `NValues`, `FormatValues`, `DefaultValues`, `Messages`, `Attributes`

All these are considered to be associated directly with the symbol, in the sense that `Attributes[x]` are considered to belong to `x` and not to `Attributes`.

Don't think of this as "Block does Unprotect, then block does ClearAll". Think of it as all symbol properties being reset to the default value, which is empty, `{}`,  except for some special builtins such as `$ContextPath` or `$Assumtpions`.

Related:

- [Copying one symbol into another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19902/12)

Comment: One could argue that the documentation is the root of a confusion since it repeats "values" which may be understood as Attributes are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer as to *why*, wolfram-language-design wise, but to how:

It seems `Block[{x = new}, ...code...]` effectively does the following:

```
newValue = new;
allValues = allValuesAndAttributesAssociatedWith[x];
Unprotect[x];
ClearAll[x];
x = newValue;
try {
    ...code...
} finally {
    allValuesAndAttributesAssociatedWith[x, allValues]
}
```

where the pseudo-code `finally`-block is executed no matter what happens inside `...code...`, even on `Abort` or `Throw`.

I tried to capture the exact order of execution of all steps.

`ClearAll[x]` clears all kinds of attributes and values associated with `x`, including `Messages`, `FormatValues` etc.