# What does the "ScalingFunctions" Method suboption of Graphics do?

Tags: graphics, undocumented

Some plotting functions produce a `Graphics` with a `"ScalingFunctions"` suboption within the `Method` option.  What does `"ScalingFunction"` do and how do I use it?  Can I use it to transform arbitrary graphics in a non-linear way?

Example:

```
g = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];

Options[g, Method]
(* {Method -> {"ScalingFunctions" -> None, 
   "TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True, "AxesInFront" -> True}} *)
```

Note:

This doesn't appear to be the same thing as [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html).

Comment: I think it scales ticks, not coordinates. It looks like the first element is affecting the range of generated ticks and the second scales their positions additionaly. Try `"ScalingFunctions" -> {# + 1 &, # + 1 &}` and `Dynamic@MousePosition["Graphics"]`. It affects only `y` axis though.

Comment: @Kuba Can you give an example?  I tried things like these and there wasn't any change in either ticks or `MousePosition`. `Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]}, 
 Frame -> True, Method -> {"ScalingFunctions" -> {# + 1 &, # + 1 &}}]`

Comment: `RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Method -> {"ScalingFunctions" -> {# + 1 &, # + 1 &}}]`

Comment: @Kuba But then you are passing the option to `RegionPlot` and not to `Graphics`.  Some of these plotting functions reinterpret options, e.g. `DensityPlot[..., PlotRange->...]` and `Show[DensityPlot[...], PlotRange -> ...]` behave differently.  Could it be that this in fact *is* a RegionPlot-specific option and doesn't even make sense for `Graphics`?  Maybe it's retained in `Graphics` by mistake.

Comment: I don't know. But `Graphics` ignores syntax that `RegionPlot` complains about (third function, different slot #2).

Comment: @Kuba That is evidence that this is really a RegionPlot option ...

Comment: It is a `RegionPlot` option, but I don't have any insight into how it works.

Comment: Actually, it seems to work like the top level `ScalingFunctions` option, i.e. pass in a `{function, inverseFunction}` pair such as `{Log[# + 2.1] &, -2.1 + 1. E^#1 &}` for the above example, at least as far as the ticks are concerned.